# The Windows lock screen is always reloaded after a timeout when my custom credential provider is installed even when its tile is not selected

Tags: windows, credential-providers, windows-credential-provider

I have developed my custom credential provider which provides a login method with RFID cards in a specific mechanism.

As you've experienced, after a timeout the curtain comes down and none of tiles are visible until you click on the curtain; But when my credential provider is installed, the curtain does not stay down after the timeout and it looks like the credential provider is reloaded which makes the curtain go up again.

I tried debugging with logging and noticed that if I do not return SUCCESS in Provider::SetUsageScenario method, the tile won't be visible and there is no reloading when curtain comes down. Hence, I tried to get a notification of the display state from Provider::SetDisplayState which is described [here](https://dennisbabkin.com/blog/?t=sequence-of-calls-to-credential-provider-in-windows#MyProvider_SetDisplayState) and to handle the response of Provider::SetUsageScenario, but I got no notifications using this method.

My provider file code is same as the [official Microsoft sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/blob/main/Samples/CredentialProvider/cpp/CSampleProvider.cpp).

Is there any other way of getting the notification?
Or is there any other way to avoid this reloading thing?

Comment: *looks like the credential provider is reloaded* - look like your code is crash LogonUI. *but I got no notifications using this method* only mean that your code is wrong